# How to bridge local LAN using Multipass

Tags: network-manager, network-bridge, lxd, multipass

Looking for some assistance in trying to get the network bridging to work (consistently/more than once) when creating VMs with Multipass.  I have tried so many things with the documentation I've found, yet nothing seems to work, or have any level of consistency.

My driver is lxd
I am using network manager
I initially used launch --network=en0, which is my physical ethernet adapter, and this worked the first time.  I was prompted to create a bridge the first time I did this, and any VM I launched would show two IPs, one for the 10.x.x.x Multipass network and the other 192.168.1.x for my local LAN and everything was great.

After one reboot of my Ubuntu server, none of that works anymore and even when attempting to launch a VM with --network= I get a single 10.x.x.x address on the VM and is not accessible from my LAN.

The Ubuntu documentation on how to configure this is not clear, at least to me, and I have to believe this is possible and shouldn't be this difficult to configure.  Any direction, tutorials, videos, blogs, instructions, anything - that somebody could throw my way to try and get this working would be hugely appreciated.

The functionality of multipass is awesome, and I would really like to use it.

Could really use and appreciate an assist here.

Thanks, all!
Bob

Comment: A common problem that occurs when folks "*have tried so many things*" is that they fail to clean up older attempts before trying something new. They leave settings changed, random config files in place, and/or conflicting new software installed. That mess left behind often prevents subsequent attempts from working properly. Ensure you have cleaned up, or the answers here won't help you.

Comment: I just tried on a new install of ubuntu 20.04 and I have the same behavior. There are vlans on the network and the host system is on a trunk. I've created the bridges but I cannot get a reliable connection. @BobBoursaw were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Almost a year later but here is a [solution I found](https://jon.sprig.gs/blog/post/2800).

Context: This worked for me using Ubuntu 22.04, and a fresh install of Multipass.

This method uses [LXD](https://ubuntu.com/lxd).

**1. Install LXD.**

```
snap install lxd
```

**2. Connect LXD to Multipass.**

```
snap connect multipass:lxd lxd
```

**3. Tell Multipass to use LXD:**

```
multipass set local.driver=lxd
```

---

Now when creating a new instance you can do so with a bridged network. For my setup it worked like this *(edit: in case it wasn't obvious, below is an example where my vm instance will be named `vm01`, and my ethernet interface name is `enp3p0`)*

```
multipass launch -n vm01 --network enp3s0
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

From the multipass [manual](https://multipass.run/docs/launch-command), use the option

```
--bridged                             Adds one `--network bridged` network.
```